# set_permissions works correctly only on administrators

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I've got a problem with my set_permissions commands. `freeze` command in my code works for every user, but `melt` command works for every user only first time. When no users have permissions on channel already, `melt` works for everyone, but when `freeze` is used, `melt` works perfectly fine only on administrators. What's the solution for this?

```
@bot.command(name="freeze")
async def zamroz(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.value == 2146959359:
            for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
                for member in channel.members:
                    if member.bot == False:
                        await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False, read_message_history=False)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Lack of permissions")
            await ctx.channel.last_message.delete(delay=2)
    except:
        pass

@bot.command(name="melt")
async def odmroz(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.value == 2146959359:
            for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
                for member in channel.members:
                    if member.bot == False:
                        await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=None)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Lack of permissions")
            await ctx.channel.last_message.delete(delay=2)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

[`channel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.members) returns a list of all members that can see the channel.

If you use the freeze command, you take away all members' permissions (apart from the bot) to read messages and message history from the channel. In other words, they can no longer see the channel.

Because of this, when running the melt command, `channel.members` will not return any members as no member can see the channel.

Replacing this with [`guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) will always return all members of the server, regardless of whether they can see the channels or not.

```
@bot.command(name="freeze")
async def zamroz(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.value == 2146959359:
            for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
                for member in ctx.guild.members:
                    if member.bot == False:
                        await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False, read_message_history=False)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Lack of permissions")
            await ctx.channel.last_message.delete(delay=2)
    except:
        pass

@bot.command(name="melt")
async def odmroz(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.value == 2146959359:
            for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
                for member in ctx.guild.members:
                    if member.bot == False:
                        await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=None)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Lack of permissions")
            await ctx.channel.last_message.delete(delay=2)
    except:
        pass
```